# C++ reading in from file to vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

My problem is that I have a base and 3 child classes and I wanted to make a vector where i can place all the elements which are representatives of all 3 child classes. Here's the part of the code which handles reading in from a file

```
vector<Robot*> robots;
vector<Mac> mac;
vector<Eco> eco;
vector<Pro> pro;
vector<int> charge;
vector<int> deliver;

try {
    string s;
    ifstream f;

    do {
        cout << "Add meg a filenevet" << endl;
        cin >> s;
        f.open(s.c_str());
    } while (!f.good());

    cout << "adatok beolvasasa..." << endl;

    int napok;
    if (!(f >> napok)) throw 1;
    charge.resize(napok);
    deliver.resize(napok);

    for (int i = 0; i<napok; i++) {
        if (!(f>>charge[i])) throw 1;
        if (!(f>>deliver[i])) throw 1;
    }

    string type, name;
    int battery;
    int m = 0; int e = 0; int p = 0;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(f, line)) {
      stringstream ss(line);
      if (ss >> type && ss >> name && ss >> battery) {

            if (type=="Mac") {
                cout << "mac" << endl;
                Mac r = Mac(name,battery);
                mac.push_back(r);
                robots.push_back(&mac[m]);
                m++;
            };
            if (type=="Eco") {
                cout << "eco" << endl;
                Eco r = Eco(name,battery);
                eco.push_back(r);
                robots.push_back(&eco[e]);
                e++;
            }
            if (type=="Pro") {
                cout << "pro" << endl;
                Pro r = Pro(name,battery);
                pro.push_back(r);
                robots.push_back(&pro[p]);
                p++;
            };
        }
    }
```

This works so far, it compiles and it runs as well, but when i try to access a function ex `robots[i].getBattery();`
the program freezes.
it seems the pointers are just pointing into nowhere but i have no idea why :(

Comment: Where's you call to `robots[i].getBattery();`? If `mac`, `eco` and `pro` are destroyed, so are their members. This leads to `robots` holding pointers to invalid objects.

Comment: They are not destroyed :/ ive written this all in the main function (hoping it would make it a bit easier) and i call it in the main function too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two independent ways of accessing your objects without any synchronisation between the two.

If you push an item into a vector and then take a pointer to it, the pointer is only valid if the vector's storage doesn't get moved or invalidated. In your case, the repeated push_back() calls might well trigger a vector reallocation and it is not guaranteed that this can happen in place, so the elements might get moved into a new memory location, but obviously the pointers are not updated. Hence, you end up with pointers to nowhere.

Having one set of containers to hold the data and another container that just holds pointers to said data looks like pretty bad design to me. As I see it, you have two options to improve the code and fix the issues you're encountering. In both cases, you only need one container to hold pointers to the polymorphic elements, it's just the way that you declare the containers:

1) Use a `boost::ptr_vector` to store the pointers to your polymorphic objects. This container is designed to hold pointers (which a `std::vector` isn't, the latter has value semantics) and takes care of lifetime management of the objects contained therein.

2) If you can't use boost, use a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Robot> >` to hold the pointers to the polymorphic objects.

In both cases, you do away with the containers that hold items by value and in your if statements, you allocate the objects on the heap and then put the pointers into the container.